# Get values from dynamically created fields and send them to PHP via Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have a page with a text field `Field name` and two buttons `(Insert field, Show fields)`.

The user inserts a value inside of the first text field that's going to be a new field's name. When he clicks on `Insert field` that value is going to be send to my database and inserted into a table called `TBL_FIELDS`.

And when the user clicks on `Show fields`, the page loads all the field names from `TBL_FIELDS` and creates **N** text fields with it's placeholders containing the names that were loaded.

These fields are shown inside of a `.fieldList` div that contains another button `Insert values` and when the user clicks on it, I want to get all the values from these dynamically created fields as well as it's placeholders and insert them into another database table called `TBL_VALUES`, this table has three columns, `ID`, `FIELD_NAME` which represents the name (placeholder) of the field and `FIELD_VALUE` which represents the value of the field.

So my question is, how can I get the values and placeholders from all these dynamically created fields and send them to my .php file via Ajax? I know I can use `.val()` to get it's value and `.attr('placeholder')` to get the placeholder but that's not exactly my point, my problem is that I don't know how many fields there will be nor how can I acess them with `$_POST`.

This is what I have so far, here's script.js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var fieldCount = 0;

    $("#btnFieldSend").click(function(){

        if($("#txtFieldName").val()) {

            $.ajax({

                type: 'post',
                dataType: 'json',
                url: 'insertField.php',
                data: { txtFieldName: $("#txtFieldName").val() }
            }).done(function(data){

                if(data.ok) {

                    $("#txtFieldName").val('');
                    alert(data.ok);
                }
                else
                    alert(data.err);
            })
        }
    });

    $("#btnFields").click(function(){

        if($(".fieldList").is(":hidden")) {

            $.ajax({

                dataType: 'json',
                url: 'selectField.php'
            }).done(function(data){

                if(data.ok) {

                    fieldCount = data.fieldCount;

                    for(var i = 0; i < fieldCount; i++)
                        $(".appField").append('<input id="' + i + '" type="text" placeholder="' + data.fieldName[i][0] + '">');

                    $(".fieldList").show();
                }
                else
                    alert(data.err);
            });
        }
    });

    $("#insertValues").click(function(){

        // send values
    });
});
```

Please, notice that I'm not asking anyone to do this for me, I know I'm not providing any code for `$("#insertValues").click()` which is going to get all the values from the fields and send them to php, and it also lacks the php code which is going to receive it. I'm just stuck and don't know what to do or how to proceed, I just need some help to guide me to a way to solve this.

If you need me to show my html, `insertField.php`, `selectField.php` or maybe my sql script, just let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give all of the inputs a name attribute so they can be sent through to your backend.

You can send through a form as a whole, as if it weren't via Ajax with `$('#formId').serialize()` specified as your Ajax function's `data` attribute.

Comment: Thank you! I've never used `.serialize()` before, really useful! I was going to ask how I could get the placeholders from the inputs but I've found a better solution by using the `TBL_FIELDS`'s `ID` as a foreign key.